# matching a regex pattern with a negative look behind

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression in Python that detects patterns like `8 cc` and `2.8 mm`  and avoids patterns with date like `12/26/2018 cc`

The regex I tried for this pattern is: `.*\d{1,}(?!/)(\s)(cc|mm|cm)`

This is supposed to find patterns like `8 cc` as long as it is not proceeded by a `/`.

This regex is finding all patterns and not avoiding the date.  What is the problem with this regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!\d)(?<!\d/)\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*(?:c[cm]|mm)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uzJde6/3)

**Details**

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit immediately to the left is allowed
- `(?<!\d/)` - no digit and `/` immediately to the left is allowed
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:\.\d+)?` - 1 or 0 occurrences of `.` and 1+ digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:c[cm]|mm)\b` - `cc`, `cm` or `mm` as whole words.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/aKY0DU):

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r"(?<!\d)(?<!\d/)\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*(?:c[cm]|mm)\b")
s = "I'm trying to write a regular expression in python that detects patterns like 8 cc and 2.8 mm  and avoids patterns with date like 12/26/2018 cc"
print( rx.findall(s) ) # => ['8 cc', '2.8 mm']
```